# Convert array of latLng values so I can POST using jQuery-Ajax

Tags: google-maps, jquery

I got an array of [latLng](http://code.google.com/intl/en-EN/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#LatLng) values and want to post this via jQuery Ajax. How did I have to convert the array?

Best regards ...

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
 var coords = ['(52.37253609047836, 4.868355474853502)', '(52.37253609047836, 4.868355474853502)', '(52.37253609047836, 4.868355474853502)'];

var coordConverted = [];

for (var i = 0; i < coords.length; i++) {
    var values = coords[i].match(/\d+\.\d+/g);
    coordConverted.push({
        latitude: values[0],
        longitude: values[1]
    });
}

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: {coords: coordConverted},
    url: 'server'
})
```

If, and only if, the server is expecting post variable array `coords`. The output looks like this:

```
{coords: [{"latitude":"52.37253609047836","longitude":"4.868355474853502"},{"latitude":"52.37253609047836","longitude":"4.868355474853502"},{"latitude":"52.37253609047836","longitude":"4.868355474853502"}]}
```

Comment: Hi,the array.toString looks like this: (52.37253609047836, 4.868355474853502),(52.36247380473571, 4.86663886108397),(52.36163517746424, 4.88037177124022),(52.36142551815929, 4.903374395751939) ... for example. There can be many values - not only two. Is there a chance to post this?

Comment: Is each item in the array a string?

Comment: The items are numbers: http://code.google.com/intl/en-EN/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#LatLng

Comment: Thanks for your help. Getting the values in a loop is easy simply with latitude:coords[i].lat(), longitude:coords[i].lng() .

Answer (score 1):

Joey was almost there.

```
lonLatArray = [....prepopulated...];
coords = [];

for(var i=0;i<latLonArray.length;i++){
    coords.push({
        lat: lonLatArray[i].lat(),
        lon: lonLatArray[i].lon()
    });
}

$.post("ajax.php",{data: coords},function(data){
    console.log("success");
});
```